# dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2

Tags: django

This is my view:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import weasyprint


    @staff_member_required
    def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
        html = render_to_string('orders/order/pdf.html', {'order': order})
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(order.id)
        weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,
                                               stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
        return response
```

when i want to import (import weasyprint) it gives me a error.

```
ERROR:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/orders/order/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
```

I already installed weasyprint and cairocffi. I'm using osx El Capitan.

Answer (score 37):

This was solved for me by installing the following dependencies on Ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0
 sudo apt-get install libcairo2
 sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Check out the dependencies at the link:

http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 16):

I also had the same issue on a fresh installation of `weasyprint` on OSX EL CAPITAN.
This is how I solved it.

Firstly, `cairo` was not found by when installed via pip, so I tried installing it via homebrew using the following command

```
brew install cairo pango gdk-pixbuf libxml2 libxslt libffi
```

Once this is done, I tried to find out the path of `cairo` installation. For my case, the location was `/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/lib/`  I just exported this to my DYLD library path

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/lib/
```

Then I uninstalled and installed `weasyprint` again

```
pip uninstall weasyprint
pip install weasyprint
```

Post that, I tried to run `weasyprint`, but got a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/bin/weasyprint", line 11, in <module>
 load_entry_point('WeasyPrint==0.31', 'console_scripts', 'weasyprint')()
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
 return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2598, in load_entry_point
 return ep.load()
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2258, in load
 return self.resolve()
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in resolve
 module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 338, in <module>
 from .css import PARSER, preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
 from . import computed_values
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
 from .. import text
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/text.py", line 216, in <module>
 'libgobject-2.0.dylib')
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weasyprint/text.py", line 212, in dlopen
 return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 139, in dlopen
 lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 770, in _make_ffi_library
 backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
File "/Users/anurag/VirtualEnvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 759, in _load_backend_lib
 return backend.load_library(name, flags)
OSError: cannot load library gobject-2.0: dlopen(gobject-2.0, 2): image not found
```

I tried to find out the location of `object` library. Found it in `/opt/local/lib` and set the fallback library path

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
```

After that, I tried running `weasyprint` again, and it worked

```
(test)anurag-mac:~ anurag$ weasyprint --version
WeasyPrint version 0.31
```

I hope someone else also finds it useful.

**UPDATE-1**

Although the above method worked, MySQL python started giving errors because of this and `culprit` was defining a fallback library path. So I removed this line

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
```

which gave me the `gobject` error again, then I tried finding the location of its installation and appended to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/lib/:/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.48.2/lib/
```

After doing that, I got a similar error for `pango`. After correcting all the errors, this is the final library path which worked

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.14.6_1/lib/:/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.48.2/lib/:/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/pango/1.40.3/lib/
```

Comment: I had to also add `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.1/lib/` to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: if you get `gobject-2.0-0 not found` you can refer this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097224/gobject-2-0-0-not-able-to-load-on-macbook). Then everything should work!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with [boxes.py](https://github.com/florianfesti/boxes/) on macOS Mojave. My solution was to install `cairocffi` with `pip3` and `cairo` with `brew`. The two commands fail on their own, but together they work for `boxes.py`:

```
pip3 install cairocffi
brew install cairo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error when using weasyprint, then you may have forgotten to install Pango, GdkPixbuf, and cairo dependencies of weasyprint which cannot be installed using pip/pip3

For Debain/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
```

For other platforms refer the below link

https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by following this link:
https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/79

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
```

http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#linux