# How to include system wide in app.yaml in google cloud?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am deploying flask app which uses `cairosvg` which is used to convert SVG to PDF. Locally app is running smoothly when I am deploying to GCP, it's not deploying and getting following error:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
[2018-05-22 18:09:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
[2018-05-22 18:09:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2018-05-22 18:09:41 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-05-22 18:09:41 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2018-05-22 18:09:42 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from api.controllers import (
  File "/home/vmagent/app/api/controllers/generateBadges.py", line 7, in <module>
    from api.utils.merge_badges import MergeBadges
  File "/home/vmagent/app/api/utils/merge_badges.py", line 4, in <module>
    from cairosvg import svg2pdf
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairosvg/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import surface
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairosvg/surface.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2')
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 38, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
[2018-05-22 18:09:42 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2018-05-22 18:09:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-05-22 18:09:42 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

On searching on google, i found [dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437041/dlopen-failed-to-load-a-library-cairo-cairo-2) but I don't know how to include in `app.yml`.

my `app.yml` file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

env_variables:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: >-
      postgresql+psycopg2://USER:PASSWORD@/DATABASE?host=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the missing dependencies are available as python packages you just need to add those to your app's `requirements.txt` file, see [Using Python Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries).

But from the answer to the post you referenced those *might* not be python packages. If so you can still create a custom runtime based on the corresponding google-supplied docker image in which you add the additional non-python dependencies your app require. From [About Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes):

> Custom runtimes allow you to define new runtime environments, which
>   might include additional components like language interpreters or
>   application servers.

See also [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).