# gobject-2.0-0 not able to load on macbook

Tags: python-3.x, flask, glib, weasyprint, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am facing this error when I start my flask application on Python3 and Mac OS:

> OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': dlopen(gobject-2.0-0, 2): image not found.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'

I am using `weasyprint` in my project which is causing this issue.

I tried to install `glib` and it is installed in my system.

Answer (score 43):

I just managed the same issue on my Mac M1.

The problem was that symlinks to the libraries were not created (can't say should it be done by homebrew or weasyprint when installation).

So, I had to do it manually

```sh
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/glib/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/gobject-2.0
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/pango/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/pango-1.0
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/harfbuzz/lib/libharfbuzz.dylib /usr/local/lib/harfbuzz
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/fontconfig/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/fontconfig-1
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/pango/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/pangoft2-1.0
```

This solved the problem.

In order to TEST if Python can find the library you may run

```py
from ctypes.util import find_library

find_library('gobject-2.0')  # Pass any other lib name as an argument
```

**UPD.** There is no such problem if you install `python` with `homebrew`.

Comment: On my system, I had to run `mkdir /usr/local/lib/` first to create the folder, as it didn't exist.

Comment: I ❤️ you man, thank you

Comment: Thank you man, it saved me a lot of time!

Comment: + You may need to install the following prior to creating soft link:

```brew install gobject-introspection```

```brew install cffi ```

```brew reinstall cairo```

```brew reinstall weasyprint```

Answer (score 6):

If you installed `weasyprint` package in your virtual env but did not installed some required packages for that, then that might be the reason. It was actually, in my case.

If you're mac user you need install `pango` and `libffi`, not to mention python as well.

[Installation guide on mac](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#macos)

```
brew install python pango libffi
(venv) pip install weasyprint
```

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the existing answers on **Apple Silicon (M1) Macs**:

If you have installed the packages with Homebrew and they are still not found or linked under `/usr/local/lib`, it is because they are installed on arm64 and found in `/opt/homebrew/lib` instead.

If you're using Python installed with Homebrew it should work without any extra work, however system Python and any managed Python versions (e.g. installed with Pyenv) will require some configuration.

#### 1. Manual symlinking

Instead of linking each library individually to `/usr/local/lib`, you can link the `/opt/homebrew/lib` contents (as long as you don't have an existing `/usr/local/lib` directory):

```bash
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib /usr/local/lib
```

This will work as long as the library you're looking for is not from a keg-only formula (those will have to be linked individually).

#### 2. Environment variables

A lot of answers point to setting some environment variable, like `LDFLAGS` or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add search paths for libraries, but these will not work with Python based on my testing:

macOS comes with System Integrity Protection (SIP) which, among other things, sanitizes your environment variables in subprocesses, for example Python. Anything starting with `LD` or `DYLD` will be purged, so setting the environment variables in your terminal profile will not work.

You can [Disable SIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection) to get these working, but Apple recommends only doing it temporarily when needed.

If you decide to go this route, here are a few options:

In Homebrew's [Github discussions](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1600) the question was answered by setting `LDFLAGS`:

```bash
export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/lib
```

Similarly you could add the necessary paths to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```bash
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot to understand why the 2nd approach wasn't working on my machine, where I have SIP enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after the homebrew update. Turned out the issue was because of the older `pango` lib version.

I did `brew install pango`

This upgraded `pango` lib from 1.48.2 -> 1.50.4 which internally installed gobject's latest version as dep. And my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues when I tried to use `weasyprint` on my Django project.

If you are using macOS, just run the following command:

```bash
brew install pango
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue and they are using both Pyenv and Homebrew, the latest Homebrew has a new command `brew pyenv-sync`. This will sync all your Homebrew installed python versions to Pyenv.