# cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0':

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, weasyprint

I have this error comming when trying to run a python script on a mac with M1.

```
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/bin/weasyprint", line 5, in <module>
    from weasyprint.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 325, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import computed_values, counters, media_queries
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..text.ffi import ffi, pango, units_to_double
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/text/ffi.py", line 406, in <module>
    'libgobject-2.0.so.0', 'libgobject-2.0.dylib',  'libgobject-2.0-0.dll')
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/text/ffi.py", line 391, in _dlopen
    return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 150, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "/Users/m/Desktop/workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 827, in _load_backend_lib
    raise OSError(msg)
OSError: cannot load library '/usr/local/lib/gobject-2.0-0': dlopen(/usr/local/lib/gobject-2.0-0, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib/gobject-2.0-0' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/gobject-2.0-0' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/gobject-2.0-0' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.70.4/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file)
```

I have followed this post instructions ([gobject-2.0-0 not able to load on macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097224/gobject-2-0-0-not-able-to-load-on-macbook)). The from command in my virtual environment finds the gobject-2.0.0 fine but the error still shows up. Any idea ?

Comment: `from` works based on the python module, but `gobject` is a system library, which needs to be there in runtime.